# Batch file to copy all new files except the most recent

Tags: copy, batch-file

I would like to write a batch file containing DOS commands (unfortunately perl or another language is not an option) to do the following task.
In one directory (c:\MyData\Directory1) there are the following files:
File2.txt
File2.dat
FileA.bin
FileQ.bin
FileC.bin
File8.bin
File2.bin
These files all have different creation dates.  The most recently created *.bin file is File2.bin in this example, but it could be any randomly named *.bin file.

In another directory (c:\MyData\Directory2) there are the following files:
File2.txt
File2.dat
FileA.bin
FileQ.bin

Here is what I want to do:
Copy all files with the extension *.bin in Directory1 that do not already exist in Directory2 *except* for the most recently created *.bin file in Directory1.  So the only files that should be copied into Directory2 are:
FileC.bin - Copy because it's a bin file that's not yet in Directory2
File8.bin - Copy because it's a bin file that's not yet in Directory2

The following files should *not* be copied into Directory2:
File2.txt - Wrong extension so don't copy it
File2.dat - Wrong extension so don't copy it
FileA.bin - Already exists in Directory2 so don't copy it
FileQ.bin - Already exists in Directory2 so don't copy it
File2.bin - Most recent *.bin file so don't copy it

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is VBScript or PowerShell also out ?

Comment: I am not sure...  The task must run from Windows Scheduler on another person's machine who is a novice programmer but familiar with batch files.  Once I give him this batch file, he needs to be able to edit it if the task changes (for example, if he changed the names of Directory1 and Directory2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DIR *.bin /o-d /b > Files.txt` to get a list of bin files ordered most recent to last. Do this on both folders (to separate output files), and then set up a FOR loop, maybe two nested FOR loops, to go through the two files, pick out the ones to copy (with special handling for the first one in the date-ordered list), and copy them from within the loop. Silly tricks would be done with setting the Attribute setting  and then using `XCOPY /M` to copy them all at the same time, but that seems overly fussy.

I've always found FOR loops to be cantankerous beasts, and if you can find a non-batch-file way, or some form of third-party plug in to help, you'd be ahead of the game.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  If I get it working I'll post the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
@rem     Sorry for excessive commenting - I am a batch file newbie
@rem     Batch file will not work if there are spaces in names of directory or copied files
@rem     Next line allows for/do loop to work correctly
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

@rem     Make temporary file that lists files from newest to oldest
DIR /o-d /b c:\temp\Directory1\*.bin > FileList.txt

@rem     Counter will be used to avoid copying newest file which is listed first
set /A Counter=1

@rem     Read in names of all files with chosen extension in the first directory
@rem     Names will be stored in the variable %%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in (C:\temp\FileList.txt) do (

@rem     Increment the counter
    set /A Counter+=1
@rem     Only copy files that are not the most recent one, so Counter>1
@rem     Requires the exclamation points because this is a string not number comparison
    if !Counter! gtr 1 (
@rem     If the file does not already exist in Directory2, copy it
            if not exist C:\temp\Directory2\%%a (
                    echo Copying C:\temp\Directory1\%%a to C:\temp\Directory2\%%a
                    copy C:\temp\Directory1\%%a C:\temp\Directory2\%%a
            )
    )
)
@rem     Remove the temporary file
del FileList.txt
```

Comment: It is possible to have too many comments; here, you do not have too many comments. Embed DOS objects (folders, files) in "quotes" to handle spaces, but triple-check everything to make sure you got it right. Otherwise, looks fine to me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Robocopy on my machine, otherwise I would do a /? and tell you.  But as I recall it has many more capabilities (especially wrt timestamps).  It's a windows tool.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy